# How could I evaluate a general 2D Gaussian Integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, gaussian-integral

Consider the following Gaussian Type Integral

$$I^2 = \frac{1}{4\pi kt}\iint_{\mathbb{R}^2}  e^{-(x^2+y^2)/4kt} \ dydx$$

I know the standard method would use the polar coordinate transformation to calculate this integral, but I am kind of lost at here since there are several letter constant involving in the exponent. Could someone help me on what would be the actual transformation like in this cases? Many thanks.

Comment: Hint l: define a new constant $\sigma = \sqrt{2kt}$ and split the double integral into the product of two single integrals. With any luck, you might even be able to recognize the integrands (especially if you factor the constant outside the integral and bring them inside the integral.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:  Switch to polar coordinates and integrate out the angle:  $I^2=\frac{1}{2kt}\int_0^\infty e^{-\frac{r^2}{4kt}}rdr$.

Step 2: Let $u=\frac{r^2}{4kt}$  Then $rdr=2ktdu$ so integral becomes $I^2=\int_0^\infty e^{-u}du=1$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I actually work this out five minutes ago, I do realize I need the second change of variables as you state at here. So, I also post my solution at here, could you help me to check it? thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I think I had the answer by myself, my calculation is blow, would someone could tell am I get right thing?
$$I^2 = \frac{1}{4\pi kt}\iint_{\mathbb{R}^2}  e^{-(x^2+y^2)/4kt} \ dydx$$

take the coordinate transformation $x = cos\theta$, and $y = sin\theta$, then the integral become:
$$I^2 = \frac{1}{4\pi kt}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^\infty e^{-r^2/4kt} r\ drd\theta$$

Take $ u = -\frac{r^2}{4kt}$, then $\ du =-\frac{r}{2kt}dr $
$$ = \frac{1}{2\pi}\cdot-\int_{0}^{2\pi}d\theta\int_{0}^\infty e^{u} \frac{r}{2kt}\ dr$$
$$ = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}d\theta\int_{-\infty}^0 e^{u} du$$
$$ = \frac{1}{2\pi}\cdot2\pi\cdot1=1$$

Comment: It is simpler (I think) if you let $u=\frac{r^2}{4kt}$ rather than the negative.  Otherwise OK.

Comment: @herb steinberg Got it, Thanks.